# AngularJS equivalent for hasAttribute()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a directive, I want to check if an element has an attribute before I execute some function on it. But I don't see anything made for that in the [jqLite docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

e.g. :

```
.directive('noReadonly', function() {

    return {
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl) {

        $element.on('focus', function() {
          if ($element.hasAttribute('readonly'))
          $element.removeAttr('readonly');
        });

      },
    }
  })
```

Comment: `if (angular.isDefined($attr.readonly)) { … }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$attr` is a object with the attributes, so you can work with it like normal:

```
if($attr.hasOwnProperty("readonly"))
```

As mentioned in the comments, this checks that the property exists. This element would result in a true response:

```
<input name="test" readonly>
```

If you want to also check for truthy values, you can extend the logic:

```
if($attr.hasOwnProperty("readonly") && $attr.readonly) {}
```

Note that attribute values are parsed as strings, so `$attr.readonly` equals `"true"` (String) and not `true` (Boolean).

Comment: Does that check if it has the property, or if the property's value has been defined?

Comment: This checks if the property exists.

Comment: This works in the `link` context. How to use this in the `compile` context?

Comment: Is there equivalent for angular 2?

Comment: If anyone's looking for a Angular2+ solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469060/angular-how-to-check-if-a-component-tag-has-specific-attribute-on-it

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($attr.readonly) {
   ...
}
else {
   //doesn't have it.
}
```