# Angular - How to check if a component tag has specific attribute on it?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I use the `app-somecomponent` in the following way

```js
<app-somecomponent required></app-somecomponent>
```

How do I check if `app-somecomponent` has the `required` attribute from the `app-somecomponent.component.ts`? I **don't** wan't to use any value for the required attribute (so `[required]="true"`, for instance is not allowed)

About the - [AngularJS equivalent for hasAttribute()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266650/angularjs-equivalent-for-hasattribute) - the `$attr` is not available in the newer versions of Angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJS equivalent for hasAttribute()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266650/angularjs-equivalent-for-hasattribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
  @Input() required;
  isRequired: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isRequired = this.required !== undefined;
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-47m2cp)

Comment: Jesus Christ, it was this simple? I could've sworn that I've tried that already, what the heck. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If there is an option that `required` can take a value, try this

```
required: boolean;

constructor(@Attribute('required') required: boolean) {
  this.required = required;
}
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. It must work without providing any value.

Answer (score 0):

[As Kaustubh Badrike said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477320/320036), if an input attribute hasn't been set at all, it will be `undefined`. A simple way to do it without `OnInit` is with a setter:

```
  @Input() set required(value: any) {
    this.isRequired = value !== undefined;
  }
  isRequired = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use viewchild decorator to get all attributes from your component

```
@ViewChild('localref', {static:true}) localref: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.localref)
  }
```

Template:

```
<app-somecomponent required></app-somecomponent>
```

Here is the working demo for the same [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d66gsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

check console to get your answer.

Comment: Always returns "undefined". Even outside of the `ngOnInit`

Comment: It really can't be like that. This would require me and my teammates to always remember to put some value on the required attribute. Common sense it to just use `required` as it is, without any parameters. That's really not what I'm looking for

Comment: You dont have to remember , you can pass required="" (empty string) or any other attribute="" , this aslo works

Comment: then after that you can check on hasOwnProperty('required'), this will work fine.

Comment: That still requires us to provide it a value. I want to use `required` and only this

Comment: Ok. i have updated my demo with  `required` only , can you pls have a look

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but it still requires us to add attributes to the tag besides `required`. The goal is to enable using is just like any other input tag.